# Can't reload app from android device

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to reload the app directly from my phone. 
I click on this button but nothing is happen.

[image]

Comment: You mean reloading the changes?

Comment: yeess i mean that

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use adb command line on your terminal.

Reload change:

```
adb shell input text rr
```

Show dev menu:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Comment: it shows me an error : ensure that the package is running perhaps am running : yarn start

Comment: Maybe the react native serve just stopped, use react-native start to start the server.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can shake your device to display developer menu on your device. And then you can choose reload to reload your app or enable live reload to automatically reload when you make some changes on your code. [Looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsRKy.png)

Comment: sorryy how can i shake my  device ?

Comment: just shake it to the left or right :D could I know which phone type you use to debug?

Comment: am using  HUAWEI KII-L21

Comment: when i shake my  phone nothing appears :(

Comment: Some devices do not support this feature, such as mine: Huawei ALE-L21

Comment: ah okkeeyy , is there  any other solution ?

Comment: have you tried to long press on back button or square button?

Answer (score 2):

have you already enable debuging for your device ?
if you haven't, please for the first time you can do it that. You can follow this way:

**1.** click the build number 4 times in the "about phone" menu to unhide the "Developer options"

**2.** then "Ensure that USB debugging is enabled under Settings>Developer options>USB debugging."

[image: Debugging Device]

If you already done. Ignore the way. And then you can try again to SHAKE your device or you can use USB to connect your phone to computer. Open your app. And press **Ctrl + M** which is old. Choose "Reload" or "Enable Live Reload" like :

[image]

I hope my answer give you ide and finish your problem. ;)

Comment: am using real devicve :(

Comment: Thanks Ctrl+M was golden, didn't even know that existed